# Why does Google display with these weird characters?

Tags: firefox, localization

I'm using the latest Firefox builds on Ubuntu 10.04, but this has happened on Windows as well, and on Chromium some time ago.

Basically, the Google home page displays as shown in the screenshot. I live in [Romania](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romania), if this has anything to do with IP address tracking.

[image]

I tried clearing my cookies, but to no avail.

Comment: Installed any new extensions or programs lately?

Comment: no new extensions for some time, no updates either (to addons or ff)

Comment: Duplicate: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5042/google-what-language-is-chr-and-why-is-my-homepage-set-there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's [a bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=580833), which sets your language preference to a long string starting with `chrome://`.  Since language strings are normally short, like `en` for english, Google's efforts to find a matching language have left them with `chr`, which is Cherokee - hence the rather pretty but not well known letters you are seeing.

You can sort this out in your browser by going to Preferences->Content->Language and selecting whichever language you prefer.

Comment: It's worth noting that the consensus in the Firefox bug thread is that the issue is triggered by using Firefox Sync on Linux